# How can I trigger an event by onselect of autocomplete element of materialize css

Tags: javascript, angular, materialize

I am using [autocomplete](https://materializecss.com/autocomplete.html) feature of materialize css.

I am able to trigger a server call from the input field and getting the JSON data and able to display the result. But I am not able to trigger event by onselect of the autocomplete item.

My code for user input:

```
<input placeholder="Search ..." class="autocomplete" type="text" (keyup)="onKey($event)">
```

The onKey() getting the server data and displaying the result as below:

[image]

The problem i am facing is while on select of any drop down value to get the selected value

Comment: Please include the code that you're using and is not working correctly. Linking to another site to describe what you're trying to do is frowned upon because those links can expire. It also means that your question is not contained within itself, making it harder for you to help other people in the future.

Answer (score 3):

Provide your onselect handler as the property `onAutocomplete` of the options object.

```js
const options = {
  data: {
    "All": null,
    "Apple": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fa/Apple_logo_black.svg",
    "Google": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/53/Google_%22G%22_Logo.svg",
    "Microsoft": null
  },
  onAutocomplete: displayResult('autocompleted as')
}
const input = document.querySelector('.autocomplete');
const instances = M.Autocomplete.init(input, options);
const resultContainer = document.querySelector('.result')

function displayResult(state) {
  return function(text) {
    resultContainer.innerText = "Input " + state + " " + text
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<p class="result">Nothing selected in input</p><br>
<div class="input-field col s12">
  <input type="text" id="autocomplete-input" class="autocomplete" onchange="displayResult('changed to')(this.value)">
  <label for="autocomplete-input">Autocomplete</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

have you tried by adding onAutocomplete function in this way

```js
$('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({
      data: {
        "Apple": null,
        "Microsoft": null,
        "Google": 'https://placehold.it/250x250'
      },
      onAutocomplete: function(val) {
          console.log(val);
      }
    });
```