# Materialize autocomplete not updating v-model of Vue app

Tags: javascript, django, vue.js, autocomplete, materialize

So I'm using Django, Vue, and Materialize. Just using Vue to have some smoother functionality.

I have a text input that has a v-model on it. I'm also using Materialize's autocomplete component on it.

When I select an option from the autocomplete, it does not update the data in vue that I have attached to the "v-model". The v-model just stays with the data I have typed in so far.

How do I get around/fix that? How do I update the vue data on materialize's autocomplete?

https://materializecss.com/autocomplete.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?

```
  mounted: function() {
    M.AutoInit();

    var options = {
      data: {
        "Emma Stone": null,
        "Batman": null,
        "Luke Skywalker": null,
      },

      onAutocomplete: function(res) {
        this.v-model_variable_name = res
      },
    };

    var elems = document.querySelectorAll(".autocomplete");
    var instances = M.Autocomplete.init(elems, options);

    console.log(instances);
  },
```

[Or this answer in stackoverflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51458301/13059645)

Did you found something since?